# How to set "CICompilerCountPerCPU" to false in Java 21

Tags: java, jit, java-21, openjdk-21

I have tried the JVM arguments like `-XX:-CICompilerCountPerCPU -XX:+CICompilerCount=3`, `-XX:CICompilerCountPerCPU=false -XX:+CICompilerCount=3`, but it still shows that `CICompilerCountPerCPU=true`:

```
[~]$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version| grep CI
     ccstr ArchiveClassesAtExit                     =          {JVMCI product} {default}
     bool AutoCreateSharedArchive                  = false     {JVMCI product} {default}
     intx CICompilerCount                          = 3         {product} {ergonomic}
```

My purpose is to set the number of JIT threads to a fixed "3", and how can I verify that was effective?

Comment: Your output doesn't actually show that `CICompilerCountPerCPU` is true.

Comment: Also, obviously, just using `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version| grep CI` will not output the desired result anyway, because then you're not setting any of those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following does the trick:

```bash
java -XX:-CICompilerCountPerCPU -XX:CICompilerCount=3 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep CICompiler
```

```
     intx CICompilerCount                          = 3                                         {product} {command line}
     bool CICompilerCountPerCPU                    = false                                     {product} {command line}
openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21+35 (build 21+35-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21+35 (build 21+35-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The obvious difference with your attempt is that you tried with `-XX:+CICompilerCount=3`, which results in an error because the `+` and `-` are only valid for boolean options:

> Unexpected +/- setting in VM option 'CICompilerCount=3'
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: I am very grateful for your professional answer!
It really works right.